# Totally remove Windows 8.1 from Toshiba Satellite laptop

Tags: windows-xp, windows-8.1, bios, uefi

I have a legacy app that will not run under `Windows 8.1`. I want to load `Windows XP` but need to totally wipe out `Windows 8.1`. I have tried going into advanced settings in the BIOS and changing UEFI to CMS but the cursor jumps over that option so I cannot do that. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

When you turn off UEFI and want to boot via BIOS (CMS) the secure boot setting needs to be disabled in most cases. When that is disabled the CMS option should light up.

Answer (score 1):

Don't wipe Windows 8.1 only to run a legacy application. Run Windows Xp in a [Virtual Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) with Hyper-V (part of Win8.1 Pro) or free tools like [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or [VMware Player](https://www.vmware.com/products/player).